# istio proxy fails to start

Tags: kubernetes, istio

I changed my istio config so it pulls the proxy image from a private repo and while the pod is able to retrieve the image and attempts to start the container it is crashing with errors and failing.

Below is the config before in the istio config map (relevant part only)

```
    "enableHelmTest": false,
    "enabled": true,
    "hub": "docker.io/istio",
    "imagePullPolicy": "",
    "imagePullSecrets": [],
    "istioNamespace": "istio-system",
    "istiod": {
      "enableAnalysis": false,
      "enabled": true
    },
    "jwtPolicy": "third-party-jwt",
```

I changed it to

```
    "enableHelmTest": false,
    "enabled": true,
    "hub": "myprivaterepo.jfrog.io/example-docker-virtual",
    "imagePullPolicy": "",
    "imagePullSecrets": ["repo-secret"],
    "istioNamespace": "istio-system",
    "istiod": {
      "enableAnalysis": false,
      "enabled": true
    },
    "jwtPolicy": "first-party-jwt",
```

As mentioned it pulls the image as normal but I get the below errors in the logs for the container. They continue on a loop and my application never starts up

```
2022-02-08T09:37:14.696190Z info    parsed scheme: ""
2022-02-08T09:37:14.696210Z info    scheme "" not registered, fallback to default scheme
2022-02-08T09:37:14.696234Z info    ccResolverWrapper: sending update to cc: {[{istiod.istio-system.svc:15012  <nil> 0 <nil>}] <nil> <nil>}
2022-02-08T09:37:14.696242Z info    ClientConn switching balancer to "pick_first"
2022-02-08T09:37:14.696247Z info    Channel switches to new LB policy "pick_first"
2022-02-08T09:37:14.696277Z info    Subchannel Connectivity change to CONNECTING
2022-02-08T09:37:14.696391Z info    Subchannel picks a new address "istiod.istio-system.svc:15012" to connect
2022-02-08T09:37:14.696490Z info    sds SDS gRPC server for workload UDS starts, listening on "./etc/istio/proxy/SDS" 

2022-02-08T09:37:14.696577Z info    sds Start SDS grpc server
2022-02-08T09:37:14.696470Z info    pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc000e3a360, {CONNECTING <nil>}
2022-02-08T09:37:14.697083Z info    Channel Connectivity change to CONNECTING
2022-02-08T09:37:14.697091Z info    Starting proxy agent
2022-02-08T09:37:14.697103Z info    Opening status port 15020

2022-02-08T09:37:14.697532Z info    Received new config, creating new Envoy epoch 0
2022-02-08T09:37:14.697604Z info    Epoch 0 starting
2022-02-08T09:37:14.703223Z info    Envoy command: [-c etc/istio/proxy/envoy-rev0.json --restart-epoch 0 --drain-time-s 45 --parent-shutdown-time-s 60 --service-cluster example-service.example-prod --service-node sidecar~10.244.1.253~example-service-fb8b7975b-292pq.example-prod~example-prod.svc.cluster.local --max-obj-name-len 189 --local-address-ip-version v4 --log-format %Y-%m-%dT%T.%fZ %l  envoy %n    %v -l warning --component-log-level misc:error --concurrency 2]
2022-02-08T09:37:14.709823Z info    Subchannel Connectivity change to READY
2022-02-08T09:37:14.709888Z info    pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc000e3a360, {READY <nil>}
2022-02-08T09:37:14.709898Z info    Channel Connectivity change to READY
2022-02-08T09:37:14.764836Z warning envoy config    [bazel-out/k8-opt/bin/external/envoy/source/common/config/_virtual_includes/grpc_stream_lib/common/config/grpc_stream.h:92] StreamAggregatedResources gRPC config stream closed: 14, no healthy upstream
2022-02-08T09:37:14.764904Z warning envoy config    [bazel-out/k8-opt/bin/external/envoy/source/common/config/_virtual_includes/grpc_stream_lib/common/config/grpc_stream.h:54] Unable to establish new stream
2022-02-08T09:37:14.774788Z info    sds resource:default new connection
2022-02-08T09:37:14.774879Z info    sds Skipping waiting for ingress gateway secret
2022-02-08T09:37:15.123059Z warning envoy config    [bazel-out/k8-opt/bin/external/envoy/source/common/config/_virtual_includes/grpc_stream_lib/common/config/grpc_stream.h:92] StreamAggregatedResources gRPC config stream closed: 14, no healthy upstream
2022-02-08T09:37:15.123096Z warning envoy config    [bazel-out/k8-opt/bin/external/envoy/source/common/config/_virtual_includes/grpc_stream_lib/common/config/grpc_stream.h:54] Unable to establish new stream
2022-02-08T09:37:15.302811Z error   citadelclient   Failed to create certificate: rpc error: code = Unauthenticated desc = request authenticate failure
2022-02-08T09:37:15.302845Z error   cache   resource:default request:b057ab28-efd6-49c5-a554-01c48f1a0c2b CSR hit non-retryable error (HTTP code: 0). Error: rpc error: code = Unauthenticated desc = request authenticate failure
2022-02-08T09:37:15.302873Z error   cache   resource:default failed to generate secret for proxy: rpc error: code = Unauthenticated desc = request authenticate failure
2022-02-08T09:37:15.302884Z error   sds resource:default Close connection. Failed to get secret for proxy "sidecar~10.244.1.253~example-service-fb8b7975b-292pq.example-prod~example-prod.svc.cluster.local" from secret cache: rpc error: code = Unauthenticated desc = request authenticate failure
```

I dont understand the failure as all I am changing is the source where the proxy image is pulled from.

The proxy image is the same one I was pulling from docker hub. I pulled it locally and pushed into my private repo

Istio version: proxyv2:1.6.3
Kubernetes version : 1.21.2
Hosted on Azure

Comment: Which version of Kubernetes and Istio did you use and how did you set up the cluster? Did you use bare metal installation or some cloud provider? It is important to reproduce your problem.

Comment: Hi Mikolaj,
Using Azure and kubernetes 1.21.2. Istio proxy v2:1.6.3

Comment: Did you see [this github page](https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/23364). You should find there a couple of ways how to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

This error

```yaml
error   citadelclient   Failed to create certificate: rpc error: code = Unauthenticated desc = request authenticate failure
```

says that the certificate could not be created. You can create it based on [this reply on github](https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/23364#issuecomment-621019030).  It is possible that the problem has been resolved. If not, try to change `values.global.centralIstiod=true`.  For more see [this reply](https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/23364#issuecomment-621538662).

See also [another similar problem](https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/26413) and possible [workaround](https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/26413#issuecomment-771665223).